# can multiple threads with different objects of same runnable class overlap

Tags: java, multithreading

Does creating a new object everytime of runnable class and passing it to Thread create multithreading problems.

For example:

```
class exmpl implements Runnable {
    int a = 0;
    exmpl(int x) {
        a = x;
    }
}

public class toRun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t = new Thread(new exmpl(5));
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new exmpl(6));
        t.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Will the two thread overlap ? ie. will the value of a for t be 5 and for t1 be 6 always?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `a` in the `exmpl` instance that you construct for the `t` thread is *initially* set to 5, and the value of `a` in the other `exmpl` instance is initially set to 6, but `a` is not a `final` variable, and you have not shown us the `run()` method.  Whether or not the two `a` fields will ever change depends on what the `run()` method does with them.

Comment: doesn't the two thread have separate copy of the instance variable 'a' ? Will what one thread does to 'a' change another thread copy  of 'a'  ?

Comment: @Tausifmohammad, not the two threads, the two _instances_.  Each time your program calls `new exmpl(n)` it creates a new instance of the `exmpl` class.  Each instance of the class has its own independent `a` field.  The only connection to threads is that your program happens to create two threads, and it gives each thread its own `exmpl` instance.

Comment: @Tausifmohammad, P.S., You should get in the habit of using capitalized camel-case names for your classes (e.g., `Exmpl` and `ToRun`).  That's what most Java programmers do, and the more you make your code look like other people's code, the better the chance that other programmers will want to read it/help you with it/collaborate with you/etc.  (https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: I will remember that. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Both **t** and **t1** are totally different objects, the value of **a** in each instance will be kept unless you modified it.

Comment: Do the threads running not change the value of a, since 'a' is an instance variable of class exmpl ?

Comment: @Tausifmohammad How could it? The first thread can't see the second instance of `toRun`, and *vice versa*.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, of course! The whole point of threads is that is so that multiple threads (even if they're different objects of class `thread` will run at once.

Think about it:

If it were impossible to run multiple threads at once, then wouldn't you just use individual methods? That way, the code would run in a single order, going from `1 to 2 to 3`.

The thing is, java has something called a `thread`. The **whole point** of this `thread` is so that instead of going from `1 to 2 to 3,` the compiler can execute **1 2 and 3** all at the **same time.**

Comment: Read the question. The question is 'i.e. will the value of a for t be 5 and for t1 be 6 always?' You haven't even addressed it, let alone answered it correctly.

Comment: @EJP Thanks for your concern, but by saying that the threads will not overlap, which was the direct question OP asked, the OP simply provided an example to strengthen the readers understanding of the question.

>Will the two thread overlap ? ie. will the value of a for t be 5 and for t1 be 6 always? Look at the stared part, OP only stated an example:

`Will the two thread overlap ? **ie. will the value of a for t be 5 and for t1 be 6 always?**`

Comment: What I meant was whether the instance variables of the class be different for different threads even when they are threads of the same class ?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia OP has confirmed the question he was asking, and you didn't address it. Still haven't.